# How to find a substring in a text file using python?

Tags: python, list

By using python I need to know how to find a substring in a text file.

I tried using in and not in function in python to find a substring from a text file but i am not clear about it

Answer (score 0):

Finding the index of the string in the text file using readline() In this method, we are using the readline() function, and checking with the find() function, this method returns -1 if the value is not found and if found it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

finding the index of the string in the text file using readline()In this method,we are using the readline()function,and checking with the find()function,this method returns-1 if the values is not found and if found it returns o